# Document -> Flash viewer, not hosted

Tags: pdf, flash, scribd

I've got a content management solution where we present scanned images (TIFF), PDFs, word docs for viewing. While we can simply embed a PDF, sometimes depending on user preferences it's a bit fiddly and sometimes not user-intuitive.

I'd like a solution like scribd, embedit, etc, but not hosted. I want to run the application on our own servers and manage it that way (for legal reasons, and our clients won't buy the service if it's hosted somewhere else).

SWFtools looks a little basic for my needs, plus doesn't do doc, docx or ppt.

Any options? Doesn't have to be free, but would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand ([Scribd](http://swftools.org/references.html)) uses swftools. And it is not basic, it is amazingly flexible. Convert everything into PDF and use swftools to convert PDF's into swf or something like Scribd does (SCB, what they call it, modified swf).

Answer (score 1):

webSupergoo has a .net component that will do this...

Their ABCpdf component can import and export a wide range of graphic and document formats, including those you've mentioned.

The installation also contains an SWF demo project that can be freely adapted, and used as the basis for a scribd-like service.

http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can try this alternative solution :

[FreepapeR](http://lededansdubocal.net/spip.php?article22).

You can display pdf documents. The pdf is converted using swftools (pdf2swf), using php on the server side or locally by hand, the user interface is written in  as3.

Hope this helps...